# Alternate SMS Sender

Tags: android

Is there any way to hook a plugin in the default SMS messaging application so that it invokes our code for sending SMS.

Can our app become an alternate SMS sender for default Messaging sending operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. There is no difference in priority with built-in SMS-apps and your app. However, the user have to choose which SMS-app is the default app.

Feel free to correct my [degree thesis](http://skogberg.eu/android/#whatisandroid) :)

Comment: I believe that he wants to replace the SMS sending mechanism in the existing messaging app and not make an entirely new app that sends SMS.